# Was it not the intention that TypeScript would handle the this scope for me?

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I am working with knockout and TypeScript .

I get an error on this:

```
AppViewModel.prototype.setActive = function (data, event) {
            this.active(data);
        };
```

from this TypeScript file:

```
export class AppViewModel {

    ///Properties
    projects = projects;
    error = ko.observable();
    active = ko.observable();
    //setActive: (data,e)=>void;
    ///Constructor
    constructor()
    {
        this.active = ko.observable();
        DataContext.getProjects(this.projects, this.error);


    }

    isActive(data)
    {
        return this.active() == data;
    }
    setActive(data, event) {

        this.active(data);
    }
}
```

Object # has no method 'active', it is bound like this:

```
<li class="nav-header">Projects</li>
            <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
            <li class="">
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.setActive, css: { active: ($parent.isActive($data)) }">
                    <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                    <span style="padding-right: 15px;" data-bind="text: title"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

$Parent should be the AppViewModel. it works until I click the link.

I am not 100% sure if the error is related to something I do not understand with binding or its the typescript generated functions and this is not proper handled.

this in a prototype function refer to the object itself? or the function scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't attempt to guess which `this` context you wanted. If you want `setActive` to always use the class instance as the `this` context, you can `bind` it in the constructor:

```
export class AppViewModel {
    ...
    constructor() {
        this.active = ko.observable();
        DataContext.getProjects(this.projects, this.error);
        this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would it be an okay as a design just to put the active variable outside the class, var active = ko.observable(), and inside the class active=active. As i did with projects. Then i dont have to worry about this.