# how to get access to classes from a Kinetic.js click event

Tags: click, typescript, kineticjs

I can't seem to get a typescript class instance within my click event.

I have a TypeScript class `Navigation`.

```
class Navigation
{
    currentPage: number;

    wireMouseEvents()
     {
        this.buttonPrevious.on("click", function(): void {
            if (this.currentPage > 1)
            {
                // do more work with Navigation objects
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the resulting JavaScript:

```
Navigation.prototype.wireMouseEvents = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.buttonPrevious.on("click", function () {
        if(_this.currentPage > 1) {
            // do more work with Navigation objects

        }
    });
};
```

The event is fired but `currentPage` is undefined.
When looking at "this" in the click event in the debugger it's a `Kinetic.Text` object.

How can I make sure the scope of the click handler is my class `Navigation`?

Comment: Could you paste the resulting JavaScript as well?

Comment: Navigation.prototype.wireMouseEvents = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.buttonPrevious.on("click", function () {
            if(_this.currentPage > 1) {            }
        });

Comment: Thanks, I flagged the answer for removal as it's not supposed to be an answer :). I'm not sure I can answer it for you, but at least it's much clearer now.

Comment: -1 because there's something wrong with the question. Paste that TypeScript into the playground and you can see it does not compile to that JavaScript. No fat arrow == no automatic `_this`.

Answer (score 0):

The Typescript you've posted doesn't compile to the JavaScript you've posted. `this.buttonPrevious.on("click", function(): void {` etc. does not generate `_this` to maintain lexical scope. Only `this.buttonPrevious.on("click", () => {` will do so. See [here](http://bit.ly/18HUCpA).

You need to use the fat arrow function to maintain scope:

```
class NavigationWithFatArrow
{
    currentPage: number;

    wireMouseEvents()
     {
        this.buttonPrevious.on("click", () => {
            if (this.currentPage > 1)
            {
                // do more work with Navigation objects
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You might also need to try binding in the constructor to ensure you always get the correct 'this'. See Ryan Cavanaugh's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16029714/1014822

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't match I copied from VS2012.  hmmm.  thanks for you suggestions; I'll look at it this morning.

Comment: Fat Arrow has the same problem.  currentPage is undefined.  I'll look at binding the constructor next.

Comment: JcFx:  Thanks for your help; I have it working.  One of the things that was throwing me off was that when I was in the click function all my class variables was saying undefined and I stopped the code b/c I thought something was wrong.  However, if I would have continued and stepped into a class method, the variables were defined.